# Dropdown fetches data from database, wanting to make another dropdown that will multiply that number

Tags: php, html

Through some help from w3school, I managed to create a dropdown for out database, which would fetch the data about a certain product fine. That function is doing great, but I want to add an option for users to decide the number of products they want. To assist with that I want a dropdown that simply multiplies the prices gotten from the first database, if that is possible.

The PHP is the following

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root2','1234','LSnet');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$con->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

if(isset($_GET['q']))

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

mysqli_select_db($con,'LSnet');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Produkter Where id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)
  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Pris</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['ProduktPris'] . ' DKK' . "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and the HTML is the following

```
 <script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../../prisdatabase.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
<body>

<form>
<select class="pris" name="NetTyper" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Vælg Nettype</option>
  <option value="1">KampNet</option>
  <option value="2">TræningNet</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Vælg Nettype her</b></div>
```

--

[Added short overview of my table in the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS8eH.png)

--

The expected output from say option one would be 595 DKK, which I would like to have the option to multiply if one would need several

Comment: please check the value for Vælg Nettype option and on the validation use if  (str == "" || str == null){alert("select NetTyper");  return false;}else{//get data}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I upvoted for encouragement, but in order to help, I am going to need a little more information.  Could you add the structure of your table/data, i.e. the columns in your `$row` variables (one example is enough).  Also, the expected output would help a lot.  We need to know what is being multiplied by what to get what!

Comment: Added an overview of my table used in the function with an one of the expected outputs